# Syntax error RunPython using xlwings, sys.path

Tags: python, excel, syntax-error, sys, xlwings

OS Windows 10 Pro

Versions of xlwings, Excel, and Python (0.9.0, Office 365, Python 3.8.2)

I am new on using xlwings through VBA. I run the exact syntax from a tutorial webpage on both VBA and Python, but it gives error like this:

```py
  File "<string>", line 1

    import sys, os; sys.path[0:0]=os.path.normcase(os.path.expandvars(r'C:\Users\User\Trial2;C:\Users\User\Trial2\Trial2.zip;C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\')).split(';'); import Trial2;Trial2.main()                                                                                                                                                               

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I used original syntax for VBA, and the syntax I used for python is like this:

```py
import xlwings as xw


#@xw.sub  # only required if you want to import it or run it via UDF Server
def main():
    wb = xw.Book.caller()
    wb.sheets[0].range("A1").value = "Hello xlwings!"


#@xw.func
def hello(name):
    return "hello {0}".format(name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    xw.Book("Trial2.xlsm").set_mock_caller()
    main()
```

I barely find any clue for this problem, so I'm hoping that someone can give me a solution

Comment: Please post the code and error as text here. For a syntax error it would make sense for us to copy and try it.... but we can't do that with a picture.

Comment: Okay, here we go. Please help @tdelaney

Comment: I bumped into a related issue where i saw EOL syntax error after i set PYTHONPATH with a windows path that contains space.  Remove the space from folder path may help.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is a long time after the initial question but I had the same issue and couldn't find an answer anywhere.  After playing around (for much longer than I care to admit) I found the problem for me was that my .xlsm/.py file names contained a space.  With no other changes, everything worked when I replaced the space with an underscore.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quirk in python's string literals. Even with raw strings the backslash escapes the quote character so `r"ends in quote\""` is valid. It also means that raw strings can't end in a single backslash. `r"ends in slash\"` is a syntax error. If you need to end a string with a backslash, you can't use raw. `"ends in slash\\"` is okay.

I'm not sure where the failing string comes from, but you need to change it to

```
import sys, os; sys.path[0:0]=os.path.normcase(os.path.expandvars('C:\\Users\\User\\Trial2;C:\\Users\\User\\Trial2\\Trial2.zip;C:\\Users\\User\\Anaconda3\\')).split(';'); import Trial2;Trial2.main()
```

See [Python Lexical Analysis](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html)

*Even in a raw literal, quotes can be escaped with a backslash, but the backslash remains in the result; for example, r"\"" is a valid string literal consisting of two characters: a backslash and a double quote; r"\" is not a valid string literal (even a raw string cannot end in an odd number of backslashes). Specifically, a raw literal cannot end in a single backslash (since the backslash would escape the following quote character).*

Comment: I understand your point, but the error happened when I run default syntax built-in in macro after I run "xlwings quickstart MyProject" in command prompt.

Fyi, I was trying to integrate python with excel using xlwings. I followed the tutorial on website, which leaded me to run python's syntax from excel. But when I hit the button (assigned with default macro), it comes an error window like I mentioned before.

It is not like I manually run the syntax, so I have no idea how to do the fixing the way you suggested me.

Comment: @bartolomeo - I was worried about that. I don't know about xlwings and the source of this string. If xlwings is generating it, then xlwings has a bug. If its coming from the tutorial, the tutorial is wrong. You'll have to address this with the source of the string.